# JavaScript - how to insert a hyperlink with dynamic label into a datatable

Tags: hyperlink, datatable

I followed the example on this link https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render and was able to insert the hyperlink into the table. However, I could not make the label of the hyperlink dynamic. Here is my code:

```
render: function (data, type, row) {


   var chipName = data.substring(data.length-6, data.length-1);

   return '<a href="'+data+'">chipName</a>';

}
```

As you can see, I defined chipName as a variable and its value is from the data. However, with this code, the label for the hyperlink is always "chipName" instead of "ABB109", "ABB110" as expected.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not concatenating chipName variable with the string.

The right code:

```
...
return '<a href="'+data+'">' + chipName + '</a>';
...
```

Comment: thank you Mircea, you solution worked like a charm.  You saved my life.lol